# Distinguishing between None and deserializing 'null' in Python

Tags: python

What is a Pythonic way to solve the problem where `None` is both a value and a default value? For example the result of deserializing the JSON value `null`:

```py
import json

class Data:
  def __init__(self, value=None):
    if value is not None: 
      self.deseralized_value = json.loads(value)
    else:
      self.deseralized_value = None

  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.deseralized_value)


# Prints "None".
print(Data())

# Also prints "None".
print(Data('null'))
```

My workaround is to define another class:

```py
class MyNone:
    pass


class Data:
  def __init__(self, value=None):
    if value is not None: 
      self.deseralized_value = json.loads(value)
    else:
      self.deseralized_value = MyNone()

  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.deseralized_value)
```

Is this an anti-pattern? An OK-ish solution? The preferred solution?

Comment: You could use the imaginary unit `1j` - this is a value impossible to encode in JSON, so it would be distinguishable from `None`. There are many other values you could use, too.

Comment: Idiomatically, you might just use a sentinel object, so just `SENTINEL = object()` or `NO_DATA = object()` or something to that effect... you could also use an `enum`, especially if there are multiple values. The nice thing a bout enums and a sentinel object is you can do things like `if data.deserialized_value is SENTINEL: do_stuff()`